# How to connect ignite web console with my kubernetes cluster pods (server and client)

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

How to connect ignite web console with my kubernetes cluster 
pods (server and client) and also let me know how to connect to SQL dB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear question but I will try to answer the way I understood it.

Under [IGNITE-7131](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7131) jira ticket you can find documentation link on [Ignite Web Console deployment in Kubernetes](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation).

The full procedure contains next steps:

1) [Install Apache Ignite cluster](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-deployment). I used [GCP installation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/google-cloud-deployment) for my needs. Just follow all the steps to successfully deploy and activate Ignite cluster.

2) [Installing Web Console in kubernetes](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation)

- [Install MongoDB](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation#section-install-mongodb)
- [Install Web Console](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation#section-install-web-console) 
  If you wont use private repository perform next steps:

  - remove `imagePullSecrets` property from `frontend` and `backend` deployments
  - use `image: apacheignite/web-console-backend` for backend in `web-console-deployment.yaml`
  - use `image: apacheignite/web-console-frontend` for frontend in `web-console-deployment.yaml`
  - above images was able to find [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apacheignite/web-console-frontend)
- [Install Web Agent](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation#section-install-web-agent)

After installing all components I was able to reach Ignite Web Console using `frontend service external-ip`

```
$kubectl get svc frontend -n web-console
NAME       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        
frontend   LoadBalancer   10.0.6.155   35.240.47.20   80:30160/TCP
```

web-console-deployment.yaml part for backend deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
  namespace: web-console
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: mail_auth_pass
        - name: mail_auth_user
        - name: mail_from
        - name: mail_greeting
        - name: mail_service
        - name: mail_sign
        - name: mongodb_url
          value: mongodb://mongodb.mongodb.svc.cluster.local/console
        - name: server_host
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: server_port
          value: "3000"
        - name: server_sessionSecret
          value: 12345
        image: apacheignite/web-console-backend
        name: backend
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: what I need to use in place of CHANGE_ME. (- name: server_sessionSecret value: CHANGE_ME) under a file called "web-console-deployment.YAML".Please give an example of that.

Comment: As per the same [documentation page](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation#section-install-web-console): `server_sessionSecret` - the password that is used to encrypt cookies; specify any value.

Comment: I provided the value - name: server_sessionSecret value: "123456789" and then tried gaurav@123, but it showing  me same error :- "Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "web-console-deployment.yaml": Deployment.apps "backend" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Required value".

Comment: have you set `image: apacheignite/web-console-backend` in `web-console-deployment.yaml` under `spec.template.spec.containers[0].image`?

Comment: you again miss configured `image` and  `name`. I have added in me reply part of config - use it

Comment: Still the same error :- "Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "web-console-deployment.yaml": Deployment.apps "frontend" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.containers[0].name: Invalid value: "apacheignite/web-console-frontend": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?'), spec.template.spec.containers[0].image: Reired value]".. Thanks for all  the help

Comment: apacheignite/web-console-backend this image having an issue "Waiting: CrashLoopBackOff "error:- enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/web-console/package.json'. Do we have any other image?

Comment: you can try another version of their image: https://hub.docker.com/r/apacheignite/web-console-backend/tags

Comment: Can you please help me with your "web-agent-deployment.yaml"